# APK not valid Google Play Developers Console

Tags: android, google-play, google-developers-console

I'm trying to upload my first app to the Google Play Developer Console, but I'm getting the error; "Upload failed, you need to upload a valid .apk file".

I followed the instructions to get a signed apk file from Android Studio and I was able to generate the apk file with no issues. The Developer Console isn't giving me any information to figure out why it is invalid! Any ideas?

[image: Invalid APK]

Comment: Is it a ".apk" file you are trying to upload?

Comment: can you try to install that apk on simulator and phone see if it's correctly formatted and generated?

Comment: It was showing up as a .apk, but I think when it was getting generated there were some issues because the file was actually just JSON

Answer (score 3):

This was eventually fixed by re-generating the signed apk a few times until I was able to get it right. The file was getting corrupted I guess. I was able to fix it by being careful to use the right Key. It was most likely just a beginners mistake! I followed this YouTube video closely and was able to do it no problem. [YouTube video on how to generate signed apk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cfxwXz6Xlag)

Answer (score 0):

Problem is related with some cookie problem. 
Log out from Google Developer Console and log in again. Also you can use browser incognito mode.